# Linux Kernel 3.3 not registering missed beacons with connected Access Point

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I'm using linux kernel 3.3 (I cannot upgrade my kernel, sorry!) and am trying to use the `wpa_cli` utility to monitor the status of my WiFi connection. I'm using an Edimax WiFi dongle to connect to a wireless access point.

I expect to see something like this:

```
# wpa_cli status
Selected interface 'wlan0'
wpa_state=SCANNING
ip_address=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Or the same thing but with `wpa_state=COMPLETED`, depending upon my connection status.

Parsing the this text output allows me to see if my wireless connection is active or scanning. However, I have noticed that after powering off my access point `wpa_state=COMPLETED` is still being returned. Using the command:

```
# iwlist wlan0 scanning
```

Forces a scan and `wpa_state` will occasionally be correct, but usually (99%) not.

Here is my `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ap_scan=1
country=US


network={
    ssid="myssid"
    psk="mypsk"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    eap=
}
```

After some investigation, I believe something weird is happening causing the kernel to return a cached version of the AP list. I am using the `RTL8192cu` driver. I've already looked at [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277465/why-does-iwlist-scan-return-cached-results-almost-every-time), and it is not the same as mine.

My belief is that the issue may be somewhere in the kernel. In the file `net/mac80211/scan.c`, at line 214 in function `ieee80211_scan_rx`, I see a `bssid` from the `BSS` of my AP appear (when AP has power) and get put via `ieee80211_rx_bss_put` ([here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/mac80211/scan.c?v=3.3#L151)). At this point, it is returned in scan results and `wpa_supplicant` causes the `MLME` layer in the kernel to authenticate and connect with that AP. However, after disconnecting AP power, I never see the `MLME` layer relinquish it's `atomic_t` hold on that `BSS`. This causes the `BSS` to never to unlinked in the function 
`cfg80211_bss_expire` at the end of a scan (`cfg80211_wext_giwscan`), in file `net/wireless/scan.c`, line 205 ([here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/wireless/scan.c?v=3.3#L199)).

Specifically, I would like to know why the atomic used to "hold" a `BSS` is not decremented on power removal from the AP - causing linux to miss sufficient beacons for a disconnect? Or, is there some configuration with wpa_supplicant I need to add to have the `MLME` kernel layer decrement it's hold on the `BSS`, or is this clearly a kernel bug?

I've already tried:

```
# wpa_cli bss_expire_age 10
# wpa_cli bss_expire_count 2
```

and have not resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of digging, I found that the issue was because of the kernel's `rtlwifi` driver. To me, it looks like the `rtl8192cu` driver was suppose to be responsible for handling missed beacons, by calling the function `ieee80211_beacon_loss`, but that call is nowhere to be found. I removed support for `IEEE80211_HW_BEACON_FILTER` in the `rtlwifi` driver and the issue has been fixed.

This [patch](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg83604.html) is essentially the same changes that I made, and the comments in this [file](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/net/mac80211.h?v=3.3#L1439) are part of what led to me this answer.